# Asp.Net Core Angular SPA Localization

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, npm

I localized my app for the German language, which works perfectly fine if I run the following command:

```
ng serve --configuration=de
```

In my Asp.Net project I have the following line of code which is used for deployment:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
```

How do I change that code to use the localized "de"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing it with the following:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --configuration=production-de" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --configuration=production-de" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
```

This required you to have an entry for `production-de` inside the angular.json file under builds.

`--prod` is short for `--configuration=production`